# Passing data to Graph2d scatter data points in vis.js

Tags: vis.js

vis.js help needed

1. Have a working example of vis.js scatter Graph2d. However, am inclined to send an additional data field that is of interest to the user. I intend to show this data on mouse click.
   However, am unable to do so?
2. Any clues as to how can I obtain the group of the data point on the scatter chart?

Any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm one of the developers of vis. This is possible although not as easily as you might like. We plan on adding support for mouse overs and clicks on datapoints but we have not gotten around to it yet.

The way you can do this at the moment is listen to the click event. This will give you a time and a value of the location where you clicked. You can then use this to loop over your data (with a radius corresponding to your dot size) and check which point has been clicked. Once you have the point you can read the contained data.

I am aware that this is a very ugly solution but until a better solution is implemented this is the only way.

If you have any more questions on this or vis in general please make an issue on our GitHub page. We are notified of these and we try to respond within a few days (hours if it's not very busy).

Cheers

Comment: Thanks @Alexdm.Am not convinced tho use the timestamp though! However, since this is the library limitation currently, am marking the answer as selected. Would look forward to the feature implementation on "id"

Comment: It depends on your data, though the timestamp and value are pretty much the x and y coordinates so matching should be easily implemented for now. We're very busy on other projects at the moment so rewriting the graph2d will have to be on the back burner for a while. I'm not sure it will happen in 2015 so if you plan to wait, just keep in mind it might be a while.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the plans. Certainly helps.

Comment: It could also be that there comes a requirement for this from some of our other projects, thereby giving it priority but for now this is the best I can do :).